# understanding jsfc attribute

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, facelets

I need help with regard to Facelets and specifically the `jsfc` attribute in HTML tags. I am having difficulty getting understanding if the following will work.

```
<head jsfc="h:head">
    <ui:insert name="head"/>
    <base href="http://localhost:8080/Jerel-Baker/"/>
        <link jsfc="h:link" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/style.css'/>
        <link jsfc="h:link" rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='styles/narrow.css'
              type="text/css"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)'
              href='styles/medium.css' type="text/css"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href="styles/wide.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>#{msg.title}</title>
</head>
```

When I put a `jsfc="h:link"` in each of my link elements, the css is not rendered. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how it's useful to use `jsfc` in a plain vanilla output component. At least, the HTML `<link rel="stylesheet">` is in JSF **not** represented by a `<h:link>`, but by `<h:outputStylesheet>`. The `<h:link>` renders a HTML `<a>` element. Technically, you should be using `jsfc="h:ouputStylesheet"` instead. I'd just get rid of the attribute since it adds nothing extra here.

Comment: Hi BalusC & thank you. I noticed this yes that the h:link renders an anchor <a>. I my be the only one using this approach, but what I like to do, is code plain xhtml templates and then convert them to jsf when I amhappy that they look good. It would be great if there were a Java based IDE with a wysiwyg editor that supported both Java fully and html languages/css. That being said I am glad I am not one of these guys who use Dreamweaver as it certainly helps to understand how to write raw code.